# Removing Vertical Center from reveal.js

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, vertical-alignment, reveal.js

I am trying to use reveal.js slide show using the zurb foundation grid as a structure for each page.

Everything is vertically aligned center with a border/padding around the edges. I can't seem to find the code in the css to remove this. Also, floats seem to be added to each tag within a section, removing them from the normal flow of the page.

Can anyone guide me to the section in the reveal.js css to reset these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

You can set the configurations in the bottom of the html as listed in the GitHub [documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration). Still working on the floats issue.

```
 Reveal.initialize({
            center: false,
```